# Secure websockets with Cro

Tags: websocket, raku, cro

**Briefly**: I created a service on an internet server using Cro and websocket. Very simple using Cro examples. No problem when sending and receiving data from an HTML page when the page is served as localhost. When the page is served using https, the websocket cannot be established.
How is the wss protocol be used with Cro?

**Update**: After installing `cro` and running `cro stub :secure`, the service.p6 has some more code not explicit in the documentation.

**More detail**:
I have a docker file running on the internet server, Cro is set to listen on 35145, so the docker command is `docker --rm -t myApp -p 35145:35145`

The service file contains

```
use Cro::HTTP::Log::File;
use Cro::HTTP::Server;
use Cro::HTTP::Router;
use Cro::HTTP::Router::WebSocket;

my $host = %*ENV<RAKU_WEB_REPL_HOST> // '0.0.0.0';
my $port = %*ENV<RAKU_WEB_REPL_PORT> // 35145;
my Cro::Service $http = Cro::HTTP::Server.new(
    http => <1.1>,
    :$host,
    :$port,
    application => routes(),
    after => [
        Cro::HTTP::Log::File.new(logs => $*OUT, errors => $*ERR)
    ]
    );
$http.start;
react {
    whenever signal(SIGINT) {
        say "Shutting down...";
        $http.stop;
        done;
    }
}
sub routes() {
    route {
        get -> 'raku' {
            web-socket :json, -> $incoming {
                supply whenever $incoming -> $message {
                    my $json = await $message.body;
                    if $json<code> {
                        my $stdout, $stderr;
                        # process code 
                        emit({ :$stdout, :$stderr })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the HTML I have a textarea container with an id `raku-code`. The js script has the following (I set websocketHost and websocketPort elsewhere in the script) in a handler that fires after the DOM is ready:

```
const connect = function() {
    // Return a promise, which will wait for the socket to open
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // This calculates the link to the websocket.
        const socketProtocol = (window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss:' : 'ws:');
        const socketUrl = `${socketProtocol}//${websocketHost}:${websocketPort}/raku`;
        socket = new WebSocket(socketUrl);

        // This will fire once the socket opens
        socket.onopen = (e) => {
            // Send a little test data, which we can use on the server if we want
            socket.send(JSON.stringify({ "loaded" : true }));
            // Resolve the promise - we are connected
            resolve();
        }

        // This will fire when the server sends the user a message
        socket.onmessage = (data) => {
            let parsedData = JSON.parse(data.data);
            const resOut = document.getElementById('raku-ws-stdout');
            const resErr = document.getElementById('raku-ws-stderr');
            resOut.textContent = parsedData.stdout;
            resErr.textContent = parsedData.stderr;
        }
```

When an HTML file with this JS script is set up, and served locally I can send data to the Cro app running on an internet server, and the Cro App (running in a docker image) processes and returns data which is placed in the right HTML container. Using Firefox and the developer tools, I can see that the ws connection is created.

But when I serve the same file via Apache which forces access via https, Firefox issues an error that the 'wss' connection cannot be created. In addition, if I force a 'ws' connection in the JS script, Firefox prevents the creation of a non-secure connection.

a) How do I change the Cro coding to allow for wss? From the Cro documentation it seems I need to add a Cro::TLS listener, but it isn't clear where to instantiate the listener.
b) If this is to be in a docker file, would I need to include the secret encryption keys in the image, which is not something I would like to do?
c) Is there a way to put the Cro app behind the Apache server so that the websocket is decrypted/encrypted by Apache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I change the Cro coding to allow for wss? From the Cro documentation it seems I need to add a Cro::TLS listener, but it isn't clear where to instantiate the listener.

Just [pass the needed arguments to Cro::HTTP::Server](https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-http-server#Configuring_HTTPS), it will set up the listener for you.

> If this is to be in a docker file, would I need to include the secret encryption keys in the image, which is not something I would like to do?

No. You can keep them in a volume, or bind-mount them from the host machine.

> Is there a way to put the Cro app behind the Apache server so that the websocket is decrypted/encrypted by Apache?

Yes, same as with any other app. Use [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html), [mod_proxy_wstunnel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) and a [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) command. Other frontends such as nginx, haproxy, or envoy will also do the job.

Comment: The approach I used is the reverse proxy one. wss is proxy passed to http and ws and the port is changed. So, the encryp/decryp is done by Apache, not Cro. It is possible to have Cro do this as described here, but I decided to separate the crypt/decrypt and App in the docker.

Answer (score 2):

Though is not a pure cro solution, but you can
run your cro app on (none ssl/https) http/web socket port - localhost
and then have an Nginx server (configured to serve https/ssl trafic) to handle incoming *public* https/ssl requests and bypass them
as a plain http traffic to your app using
nginx reverse proxy mechanism (this is also often referred as an ssl termination), that way you
remove a necessity to handle https/ssl on cro side.
The only hurdle here might be if a web sockets
protocol is handled well by Nginx proxy. I’ve never tried that but probably you should be fine according to the Nginx docs - https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/